# Wake up a Z-Wave node programmatically

Tags: node.js, z-wave

I'm looking for away to wake up a node programmatically, but I don't even know if it's possible.

The Context : I wrote a nodejs application that aim to interface z-wave modules thanks to [node-openzwave-shared](https://github.com/OpenZWave/node-openzwave-shared) . 
Every things works fine with lights but I recently got a PIR sensor that is sleeping directly when I start my nodejs application.
Does anyone know how to wake up my PIR sensor programmatically ? (I can wake it up by pressing a physical button but this solution does not satisfy me)

NB : What is the difference between a sleeping node and a awake node ? (I mean technicaly speaking) It'seems that sleeping node can't receive controller command but can anyone confirm this please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sleeping devices can't be woken up pro grammatically, but most offer settings that can be changed to periodically wake up and provide updated sensor data as well as accepting commands.

I have a battery powered motion/light/temperature/humidity sensor that does that.  It wakes on movement or provide a status update every 10 minutes.

Sleeping, on z-wave, just means non-responsive. From a device standpoint, it probably just means a powered down transmitter/receiver.

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the following point : "Sleeping, on z-wave, just means non-responsive."